# PHP e Javascript - Automatizando função de impressão de uma página a partir de outra página

Tags: php, javascript, html, session, impressora

O meu site possui uma tela de consulta de eventos cadastrados. Para cada um, tenho a opção de Editar Evento que me redireciona para um formulário:

```js
    function editaEvento(val){
        var valor = val;
        location.href = "http://meusite.com.br/edicaoeventos?valor="+valor;
        // Função de edição pra abrir a página de formulário, semelhante ao do Index, mas que somente fará a edição
    }
```

Dentro do formulário de edição há um botão pra imprimir esse formulário. Estava querendo criar uma nova função pra Imprimir o evento a partir da consulta de eventos cadastrados.

Como eu posso fazer? Pensei em algo do tipo: repetir a função editaEvento e adicionando um valor de `$_SESSION['imprime']` igual a `1`. Aí quando a página de edição carregar, ela faz uma verificação do valor da session. Se continuar como `1`, ele ativa a impressão do formulário automaticamente.

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Fala chará. 
Você pode criar no botão de Impressão onclick="window.print()"
E no CSS usar a imaginação do css com o @media print
Acho que o caso da session é complicado pois a verificação é mais complexa, tenta utilizar o print() mesmo e ocultar os campos que não devem ser mostrados na impressão.
Ou senão criar um eventosimpressao.php?idevento= 
e nesse arquivo configurar os moldes. Só que é mais complicado. 
Ex:
    
        @page {
            size: A4;
        }

```
@media print {
    body{max-width: 100%}
    thead {display: table-header-group;}//bug do firefox
    #btnSave{display:none;}
    #btnCancel{display:none;}

}
```